# Limit checks in DataGridView CheckBox

Tags: c#, checkbox, datagridview

[image]I have a `DataGridView` with `CheckBox`, now my question is how do I set a limit on how many `CheckBox` can be `checked` into say like 3? I already have the code for counting how many `CheckBox` is checked. I am new to programming and sorry for my bad English.

```
private void DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
        bool isChecked = Convert.ToBoolean(DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());

        if (isChecked)
        {
            num += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            num -= 1;
        }
        MessageBox.Show(num.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Put a breakpoint on num += 1.  You essentially want to replace num +=1 with "if (num >= 3) theCheckbox.value = false; else num += 1;"  I'm not on an MS box at the moment, so I can't give you the exact syntax, but you need to learn how to discover this for yourself.  With the execution stopped on the breakpoint, hit ctrl g to open the immediate window.  Type DataGridView1 and hit enter, you'll see the object.  Follow up with DataGridView1.Rows[DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[0] and look at what's available.  If nothing looks promising add .Value.  Try setting .Value to false.

Comment: By playing around in the immediate window, you can find the property you need, which will sometimes be buried in a seemingly arbitrary number of layers of other objects.

Answer (score 1):

This example allowes checkboxes to be changed only 3 times. Before going into editmode there is a check whether the checkbox has been changed for 3 times. If it does, the editmode will be canceled. On every commited edit a counter will be updated in the `Tag` property of the cell.

```
dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit += ( sender , e ) =>
{
    var dataGridViewCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    if ( dataGridViewCell.ValueType == typeof(bool))
    {
        var checkedCount = dataGridViewCell.Tag is int ? ( int )dataGridViewCell.Tag : 0;
        e.Cancel = checkedCount == 3;
    }                
};
dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += ( sender , e ) =>
{
    var dataGridViewCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    if ( dataGridViewCell.ValueType == typeof(bool))
    {
        var checkedCount = dataGridViewCell.Tag is int ? ( int )dataGridViewCell.Tag : 0;
        dataGridViewCell.Tag = checkedCount + 1;
    }
};
```

This example allowes only 3 checked checkboxes in the grid:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int _checkedCount;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        dataGridView1.CellBeginEdit += ( sender , e ) =>
        {
            var dataGridViewCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            if ( dataGridViewCell.ValueType == typeof( bool ) )
                e.Cancel = _checkedCount == 3;
        };

        dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += ( sender , e ) =>
        {
            var dataGridViewCell = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
            if ( dataGridViewCell.ValueType == typeof( bool ) )
                _checkedCount += 1;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I put these on a listener?

Comment: These events should be initialized only once. You can place this in the constructor of your form, right after the InitializeComponent(); call

Comment: It says (; expected) the int i and in the colon.

Comment: I don't get that syntax error. I've updated the answer with the form constructor code.

Comment: Go to your project's properties and look at Build => Advanced and change the Language version to C# 7.0. That will cause a more explicit compile error on the build machine.

Comment: I only have up to C# 6.0, tried it but same result. Thank you for answering my questions sir.

Comment: I've changed the code in the answer so you can compile it on C# 6.0

Comment: Okay there's no error now, but still it doesn't prevent me from ticking more than 3 checkboxes.

Comment: The edit is only being pushed to the grid when you move out of the cell

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. I am trying to restrict a user from ticking more that 3 checkboxes,

Comment: In the whole grid?